# suppress calling __init__() of parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I just noticed some unintended behaviour then tested it in an interpretor (Python 3.5.3):

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print("nothing important")
... 
>>> a = SomeClass()
nothing important
>>> class SomeOtherClass(SomeClass):
...     pass
... 
>>> b = SomeOtherClass()
nothing important
>>>
```

I thought you needed to directly call the parents `__init__()`. What is the simplest way to write or instantiate the child class such that it does not run the `__init__()` from the parent class?

Comment: The whole point of inheritance is code reuse. You could override `__init__` in the subclass. Maybe you don't want inheritance at all?

Comment: No, I want some methods from the parent, just not that the init runs.

Comment: define `__init__` in `SomeOtherClass` as well?

Comment: *Not* calling `__init__` breaks the contract that an instance of `SomeOtherClass` is-a instance of `SomeClass`. Consider that `SomeClass.__init__` should be redefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can by defining an `__init__` method in the child class:

```
class SomeOtherClass(SomeClass):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Remember that this implementation will be passed along to subclasses of `SomeOtherClass`.  You are not "deactivating" `__init__` for a single class here (unless there are no further subclasses).

Comment: Thanks, okay well it looks like you just have overwrite it. I thought there might have been some kind of trick to stop it running when you inherit or instantiate it.

Comment: @cardamom you're welcome.
@timgeb That's a very good observation, but that may be what the OP wants, maybe there will be no more subclasses, and if there are, won't this `SomeClass.__init__(self)` solve the problem?

Comment: @MrGeek It does make a lot of the code with `super().__init__(self)` and `Base.__init__(self)` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) seem rather redundant if it calls on instantiation anyway..

Comment: @cardamom Not exactly, most of time the subclasses contain additional information and are therefore instantiated differently from their parent class, e.g.: `Shape()` may have an `area` property, subclass `Circle(Shape)` has a `radius`, and `Shape` class doesn't have, so more variable instantiations is required in the `__init__()` of the `Circle` class, after the `super.__init__()`, which initializes `Circle` objects with properties that are both in `Circle` and in `Shape`.

Comment: Thanks @MrGeek this questions seems to have stirred up some emotions in the community.. Now that I think of it, it is probably more pythonic to turn the methods I need into `@staticmethod` 's than to instantiate it and suppress the init like this.

Comment: @cardamom You're welcome, and it's up to you what style you choose.

Comment: @cardamom If you want only to reuse part of the code (implementation inheritance, vs type inheritance), then you should extract common behaviours into a mixin class (a class that only have behaviors - no state) and make both `SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` inherit from this mixin.

Answer (score 3):

> I want some methods from the parent, just not that the init runs

Then your design is wrong. If you only care about code reuse but not proper subtyping ([as defined by Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), proper designs are either composition/delegation or (probably the best in your case) multiple inheritance with mixin classes:

```
class CommonMixin():
    def method1(self):
       pass

    def method2(self):
       pass


class SomeClass(CommonMixin, SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print("nothing important")


class SomeOtherClass(CommonMixin, SomeOtherBaseClass):
    pass
```